# How to get the indexPath of tableView and use the indexPath on the metod prepare(for segue: )

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have a Tableview that shows a section with 7 rows, what I want to do is that when I press row 0 I send it to another view, all the information in the table is loaded by code using fixes, my question is how can I get the indexPath in the "prepare ()" method and how the segue should be done in a programmatic way.

This is my class where I have all the code in my TableView:

```
//
//  ControlTablaPrincipalTableViewController.swift
//  Seccion 15
//
//  Created by Barbatos on 7/10/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Seccion 15. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ControlTablaPrincipalTableViewController:UITableViewController {

    var titulos : [String] = ["Caja de ahorro","Blog de la Seccion 15","Iniciar Sesion","Galeria de eventos","Convenios", "Ubicacion", "Contactanos"]

    var imagenes : [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "caja"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blog"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "sesion"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "galeria"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "convenio"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ubicacion"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "contacto")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return titulos.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.imageView!.image = imagenes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = titulos[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Celda seleccionada", message: "Se selecciono la celda \(indexPath.row)",preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is my **didSelectRowAt** method where I programmed an alert that will show me which cell I am programming:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Celda seleccionada", message: "Se selecciono la celda \(indexPath.row)",preferredStyle: .alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(okAction)        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)   
   }
```

This is the **prepare** method where I try to recover the selected cell and program an if to be able to use my segue:

```
overrider func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
            if(selectedRow == 0){
               segue.destination as? CajadeAhorroViewController 
            }
    }

}
```

The identifier of my segue is "caja":

[image]

Comment: Unrelated but in a subclass of `UITableViewController` `datasource` and `delegate` are connected implicitly. The two lines in code are redundant. And **do not** use multiple arrays as data source. Swift is an object oriented language. Use a custom class or struct. If you connect the segue to the **cell** rather than to the view controller the cell is passed in the `sender` parameter in `prepare(for` and you don't need `didSelect`.

Comment: @vadian So you recommend me to use something like MVC?

Comment: Yes, I do. It's more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to just perform the segue inside the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function...

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
           didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "caja", sender: nil)
    case 1:
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "whatever you set this identifier to", sender: nil)
    // cases for all the different rows...
    }
}
```

If you only have one segue and you need to switch the variables of the view controller it shows differently based on the cell selected

```
overrider func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
       let destination = segue.destination as? CajadeAhorroViewController {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            // destination is the "CajadeAhorroViewController", set its properties for how you want it.
        case 1: 
        // ... all 7 cases ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already use your solution and it gives me this error: 

while an existin transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be update

Comment: Sorry, I saw the problem, it was because of the alert that showed